# Spring Integration JMX support not work

Tags: jmx, spring-integration, spring-jmx

As far as I know Spring Integration has out of the box JMX support. What documentation says is that I can obtain numerous statistics regarding channels, routers, etc.

I have the following configuration added to Spring context file:

```
<context:mbean-server />
<context:mbean-export/>
```

However, only one element has been auto detected for JMX exposure. It is a simple *delayer*.
I have multiple flows defined and no more elements are exposed through JMX. 
I have no clue what is wrong.

Are there any other configuration changes I need to make?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `<int-jmx:mbean-export>` instead.

Sorry for the short answer, but there is no more to say, if already have taken a look into Docs.

However here is a [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/jmx) on the matter.

**UPDATE**

H-m. No, wrong sample. See Spring Integration [tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-jmx/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration_/mbeanexporterhelper).

**UPDATE2**

`<context:mbean-export/>` registers MBeans for those Spring Beans which are `@ManagedResource`. The `<int-jmx:mbean-export>` goes a bit further and wraps to MBeans almost all Spring Integration components: `channels`, `MessageHandlers`, `MessageSources`.
And yes, adds for them `@ManagedMetric`s.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer. You are right. Changing *<context:mbean-export/>* to *<int-jmx:mbean-export>* solves the problem.